# String split to object with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Given:

```
    class T
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    string s = "A|B";
```

Is there a way to split s on the | and return a T object "inline"? I know I can do something like:

```
s.Select(x => { string[] arr = s.Split(); return new T() { A = arr[0], B = arr[1] };
```

But I'm wondering if there is some obscure linq thing to do it "inline" without declaring the array and splitting inside of the select. Something more along the lines of:

```
s.Split().Select(x => new T() { A = x[0], B = x[1] });
```

Obviously that'll give you a compiler error, but you get the idea... is there a way to do it like that?

Comment: `s.Select()` is going to return three of those things.

Answer (score 3):

If you use query syntax then you could do something like this:

```
var strings=new string[] { "A|B","C|D"};
var query= from s in strings
           let x=s.Split('|')
           select new T{ A = x[0], B = x[1] };
```

### Update

If `"A|B"` is the data source I don't recommend use Linq for that, you just could do:

```
    var arr= str.Split('|'); 
    var instance=new T{A = arr[0],B=arr[1]};
```

Or do the same in the constructor as @James recommended in his answer.

Comment: This returns 3 T's.

Comment: Please show your data source  and the result you are expecting to give an accurate answer

Comment: That was the data source: "A|B" as a string. I want to split it and create a SINGLE T object. A = "A", B = "B". I can do it by doing the split in the lambda as I indicated, but I wondered if there was a way to do it inline.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really better than what you originally had, but this is one way (if s is a `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
s.Select(x=>x.Split('|')).Select(x=>new T{A=x[0],B=x[1]});
```

if s is a single string, then you would do:

```
new List<string>{s}  // Now List<string> with 1 string in the list
.Select(x=>x.Split('|')) // now IEnumerable<string[]> with 1 string array in it
.Select(x=>new T{A=x[0],B=x[1]}) // now IEnumerable<T> with 1 T in it
.First(); // Now just T
```

Comment: I was writing the method syntax solution ;)

Comment: What is `s`?  Is it a string or a collections of strings?

Comment: But isn't this going to create multiple `T`s?

Comment: @JamesCurran, good point.  He had it as a single string, but I'm using it like it was a collection of strings.  His example uses it like a collection of strings too though.

Comment: Hmm... that works... but it creates a new list and 3 T's, then just filters it down to one later... I was hoping there was some obscure way to do it :). Oh well...

Comment: Updated answer with comments to show the various stages of the LINQ chain.  There is only 1 `T` that gets created, but it is in an `IEnumerable`.  The `.First` just grabs the only T in the `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in one line, sure:

```
var s = "A|B";
var t = new T{ A = s.Split('|')[0], B = s.Split('|')[1] };
```

But obviously that uses `Split` twice and it looks bad.

This is probably a sign that you need a method:

```
private static T ParseT(string s) {
    // do the conversion *properly* here
}
```

Then you can just call it:

```
ParseT("A|B")
```

Alternatively, add an explicit (recommended) or implicit conversion:

```
public static explicit operator T(string s) {
    // do the conversion *properly* here
}
```

Comment: The last answer is probably best if you have access to the T class, and the first answer is best if you are only doing a single string (better than LINQifying)

Answer (score 1):

Why fight actual language concepts:

```
void Main()
{
    var strs = new List<string> { "A|B", "CCC|DD", "E|FFF"};

    var Ts = strs.Select(s =>s.ToT() );
    Ts.Dump();
}

static class Ext
{
    static public T ToT(this string str)
    {
        return new T(str);
    }
}

public class T
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public T(string str)
    {
        var arr= str.Split('|'); 
        A = arr[0];
        B = arr[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE I do not recommend doing it this way this was more of a fun way to do.

```
public static T CreateLinq(string s)
        {
            return s.Aggregate((a: new StringBuilder(), b: new StringBuilder(), c: false),
                (acc, c) => (a: (!acc.c && c != '|' ? acc.a.Append(c) : acc.a),
                             b: (acc.c && c != '|' ? acc.b.Append(c) : acc.b),
                             c: acc.c || c == '|'),
                acc => new T { A = acc.a.ToString(), B = acc.b.ToString() });
        }
```

And the performance is not as bad as it seams on the first glance.

```
public class T
        {
            public string A { get; set; }
            public string B { get; set; }
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var s1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, i) => acc.Append("A")).ToString();
            var s2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, i) => acc.Append("B")).ToString();
            var text =$"{s1}|{s2}";

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                Console.WriteLine("Start");
                sw.Start();
                var t1 = CreateT(text);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                sw.Reset();

                sw.Start();
                var t2 = CreateLinq(text);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                sw.Reset();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static T CreateLinq(string s)
        {
            return s.Aggregate((a: new StringBuilder(), b: new StringBuilder(), c: false),
                (acc, c) => (a: (!acc.c && c != '|' ? acc.a.Append(c) : acc.a),
                             b: (acc.c && c != '|' ? acc.b.Append(c) : acc.b),
                             c: acc.c || c == '|'),
                acc => new T { A = acc.a.ToString(), B = acc.b.ToString() });
        }

        public static T CreateT(string s)
        {
            var split = s.Split('|');
            return new T { A = split[0], B = split[1] };
        }
```